# The continuation token specified in the request is malformed

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

I'm really having a hard time trying to make pagination work with documentDB with the node SDK.

This is what i have:

```
find: function (querySpec) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var options = {
                maxItemCount: 2
            }
            var query = self.client.queryDocuments(self.collection._self, querySpec, options);
            query.executeNext(function (err, results, headers) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    self.continuation = headers['x-ms-continuation'];
                    resolve({ 'results': results, 'resource': headers['x-ms-resource-usage'] });
                }
            })
        });
    },


nextPage: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.continuation)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var options = {
                maxItemCount: 2
            }
            self.continuation ? options['continuation'] = self.continuation : '';
            var query = self.client.readDocuments(self.collection._self, options);
            query.executeNext(function (err, results, headers) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve({ 'results': results, 'resource': headers['x-ms-resource-usage'] });
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

**Continuation Token:**
`{"token":"-RID:K0JYAKIH9QADAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:2","range":{"min":"","max":"FF"}}`

**Return Error:**
`{ code: 400,
  body: '{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"The continuation token specified in the request is malformed. Please re-run the query without it and iterate.\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: 9e04278a-3808-4a59-8e63-dae191ef3519, Request URI: ...."}',
  activityId: '9e04278a-3808-4a59-8e63-dae191ef3519' }`

So basically I'm loading the page with limit of 2 items. Then for next page I'm sending the continuation token, but I'm getting back the error malformed token.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like Microsoft support on their products are really limited to non existent. Documentdb has so many limitations that I'm moving away from it. Use mongodb instead.